# What does 8W8 or 7W2 stand for in connector description?

Tags: connector, interconnect

Pretty straightforward from the title.

Comment: No it is not. What connector? Link? Datasheet?

Comment: Yesitis. 

I am kidding, here for example https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/CONEC/3008W8SXX99G40X?qs=sGAEpiMZZMv3qGlUeJulROY6JlK2kmCUw1LOvBFDLNLDWR5U2FJiQA%3D%3D

Edit: I get first '8' means 8 positions, but what does 'W8' stand for then?

Comment: It is literally on page 3 of the data sheet "Shell size and Design".

Comment: It stands for whatever this particular manufacturer has decided it stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. From page 2 | 6 of the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ie/datasheet/2/81/CONEC_08302018_DSubCombinationStandard-1398328.pdf).*

- First number group gives the total number of pins.
- W is the separator. Think "wide".
- Second number group gives the number of "wide" pins.

This answer is totally made up.